# Doing a POST from server in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement Sage Payment Gateway in MVC.
There will be no form to accept user input instead there will be a button which takes the user to Sage website with user/shopper cart data.

I have the cart data in XML that Sage expects.

Generally I would have a from on the my page and can put the action params and method type to 'POST' and that would work.
In this case the data to be posted is on the server and the post has to happen from the server.

How do I go about posting data from one server to other and get a response?

I know this is a very basic question but I am new to MVC and web programming so any guidance on this is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a comprehensive answer, but it might put you on the right path.

We can use the .NET class [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) for this.

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest;
HttpWebResponse webResponse;
Stream dataStream;
byte[] dataBuffer;

string xml = "<xml></xml>";

// set up our request

webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com");
webRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

// prepare our XML as data to be sent

dataBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);

dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();

dataStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);

// post and get response
webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
```